# The "easier" case in Knudsen's stabilization of pointed curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

My question concerns Knudsen's (super-important) proof that $\overline{M}_{g,n+1}$ is the universal curve over $\overline{M}_{g,n}$ (F. Knudsen, *The projectivity of the moduli space of stable curves II: the stacks $M_{g,n}$*, Math. Scand. 52 (1983)), more specifically the proof of Theorem 2.4.

Using notation as in Knudsen's paper, in Case II of the proof, I don't understand how it follows from Corollary 1.5. that $X^\mathrm{s} \to S$ is flat and prestable.

I don't know what is Corollary 1.5 applied to. If it's $X^\mathrm{s}$ in the role of $X$, $X$ in the role of $Y$, and ${\mathcal O}_{X^\mathrm{s}}$ in the role of ${\mathcal F}$, then the issue is that the flatness of ${\mathcal F}$ over the base is a hypothesis in Corollary 1.5, so we can't use that to argue that $X^\mathrm{s} \to S$ is flat.

Am I missing something obvious? It's extremely possible. If not, what would be the right way to fill in the details?

P.S. As an aside, it is known that some details are missing in Case I (which should be the "hard" case), and these are addressed in a much more recent paper by Knudsen (*A closer look at the stacks of stable pointed curves*, J. Pure Applied Algebra, 2012), as well as a related paper by R. Ile ( https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.3909 )

(Edit: changed $X_s$ to $X^\mathrm{s}$.)